# What are the empty sockets on items for in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm running across certain items that when I examine them say "empty socket".

I've tried searching Google to no avail. I'm assuming you can maybe attach something else to them? Can anyone explain what they're for? If you have links, I'll gladly take 'em so I can read up, too.

Comment: someone care to explain the negative vote? seeing as this is my first diablo game, seeing as i dont see a clear way to examine said slot, seeing as how when i searched on here theres no clear definition...GOOD job!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Empty socket" means you can attach certain gems to the item. Gems have various stats when found which will affect the stats that the item gives when equipped.

In act II you will find the "Jeweller". The jeweller will allow you to upgrade your gems (3 of each kind) to the same gem of a higher quality.

You will find more information about gems on http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/gem/

Happy gem hunting! (Hint: for lvl'ing, equip a ruby in your helm for extra %experience from monsters)

Comment: Thanks User28039, clear,concise and useful lol. Loving this game and this made it all the better lol. Thanks..i just got to act 2 so...time to find this jeweler

Comment: You're welcome! Diablo III is yet another great blizzard game! :-) You should also try Diablo II one day - it's still one of the best games ever made imho!

Comment: @somdow You don't have to search for him. Just play the act normally and he'll be impossible to miss.